# Prove that every prime ideal of $R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. (proof check request)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity such that for each $a \in R$ there is a positive integer $n$ greater than 1 such that $a^n=a$. Prove that every prime ideal of $R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

My attempt: 
Let $I$ be a prime ideal and assume $A$ is an ideal of $R$ that contains $I$. Let $a \in I$. Then $a^n \in I$ also and so $a + a^n = a( a^{n-1}+1) \in I$.

Since $a \in I$ and $I$ is a prime ideal, $a^{n-1} +1 \notin I$, but $a^{n-1}+1 \in A$. This implies $a^n \in A$ and $1 \in A$. Since $1 \in A$, we must have $A = R$. Since $I$ is properly contained in $A =R$, the prime ideal $I$ must be maximal.

Comment: Why $a^{n-1}+1\in A$?

Comment: Hint: $0=a^n-a=a(a^{n-1}-1)\in I$.

Comment: Hm, since $I$ is contained in $A$, I'm thinking if $a+a^n = a(a^{n-1}+1) \in I \subset A$, then both $a$ and $a^{n-1}+1$ must be in $A$. Is this not true? If so, my argument is not valid.

Comment: It's nice that you've done your work, but if you want your solution evaluated, you should post it as a solution to existing copies of this question, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/866288/29335). There is no sense in posting a separate request to "check me" for every possible string of symbols that proves a problem. That is only one duplicate out of many, actually.

Comment: @rschwieb ah, I see. I didn't realize I could do that! Thank you for the link and advice on how to approach getting my work evaluated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is flawed where you state that $a^{n-1}+1\in A$. For the proof, assume $I\subsetneq A$ and take $a\in A\setminus I$. There exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{n}=a$. Thus

$$I\ni 0=a-a^{n}=a\left(1-a^{n-1}\right)$$

$I$ is prime and $a\notin I$, forcing $1-a^{n-1}\in I\subsetneq A$. But $a\in A$, and therefore $1\in A=R$ - which proves that $I$ is maximal.

Comment: Why does $a \in A$ imply $1 \in A$?

Comment: Oh, is it because it's for each $a \in R$? Since $R$ is a ring with unity, we have $a=1 \in R$?

Comment: @blueskyscroll Because $a\in A$ implies that $a^{n-1}\in A$. Together with $1-a^{n-1}\in A$ this proves that $1=\left(1-a^{n-1}\right)+a^{n-1}\in A$.

Comment: Oic, thank you for the explanation